# xelatex: Minted code block represents tabs as ^^I

Tags: xetex, minted

I am producing LaTeX output with org mode.  My code snippets wind up being indented with tabs, because of my c-mode settings.  Changing these would be inconvenient.  Although the snippet I am posting could be compiled with latex, I need to be able to compile Unicode documents, so I am using xelatex -shell-escape to compile the automatically generated latex source.

The generated source looks like this:

Which produces LaTeX like the following (some irrelevant stuff removed, this reproduces the problem):

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{article}
 \tolerance=1000
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{minted}
 \author{Glen Stark}
 \date{\today}
 \title{sample}
 \begin{document}

 \section{Foo}

 \begin{minted}[]{c++}
 void foo()
 {
     void bar = fb();
     std::cout << "fbar" << "\n"
 }
 \end{minted}
 \end{document}
```

Compiling this with `xelatex -shell-escape` results in output like:

> void foo()
>
> ^^Ivoid bar = fb();
>
> ^^Istd::cout //etc.

The whitespace in the minted block is a tab.  Obviously xelatex is inserting something funny in place of the tabs.  I have a workaround where I force generation of spaces instead of tabs, but this is inconvenient.

Anyone know what the fix/problem is?

Answer (score 9):

The problem is pretty similar to the one described in [Tabs in output file written by xelatex and pdflatex are different](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14771/tabs-in-output-file-written-by-xelatex-and-pdflatex-are-different)

The solution should be to call `xelatex` with the `-8bit` option:

```
xelatex -8bit -shell-escape test
```

Here's the `test.tex` example I used, to show that two byte characters are honored in comments nonetheless.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\begin{minted}[]{c++}
// comment éßàł
void foo()
        {
                void bar = fb();
                std::cout << "fbar" << "\n"
        }
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

(Note: the interface of StackExchange changes tabs to spaces, so change them back for testing.)

[image]

Comment: [Newer XeTeX releases apparently use `--enable-8bit-chars` instead of `-8bit`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385054/38074)

Comment: @ComFreek I get ``unrecognized option `-enable-8bit-chars'`` on TeX Live.

Comment: It seems you only typed one dash. Does it work with two?

Comment: @ComFreek No, it doesn’t. TeX Live programs accept one or two hyphens. I think it’s only a MiKTeX option.

Comment: `xelatex -8bit -shell-escape` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The `-8bit` option doesn't work for me, it just causes xelatex to throw up a compilation error when processing the .pygtex auxiliary file that I can't resolve. What does work for me is saving my function into its own source code file and using the `\inputminted` command to import into latex:

```
\inputminted{c++}{foo.cpp}
```

Whitespace characters are then represented correctly.