# No -8bit with xelatex

Tags: xetex, miktex, input, characters

I wanted to use verbatim with beamer document class, but I noticed that all the tabs are replaced by ^^I.

A solution has been given to this problem [Tabs in output file written by xelatex and pdflatex are different](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14771/tabs-in-output-file-written-by-xelatex-and-pdflatex-are-different)

But to solution requires that -8bit is added on the command line of xelatex.
If I try to do that, I get the following error in xelatex.log:

```
2017-05-24 14:26:10,919+0200 INFO  xelatex - starting with command line: xelatex -8bit document.tex
2017-05-24 14:26:10,927+0200 FATAL xelatex - The command line options could not be processed.
2017-05-24 14:26:10,927+0200 FATAL xelatex - Info: optionError="unknown option"
2017-05-24 14:26:10,927+0200 FATAL xelatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\webapp.cpp
2017-05-24 14:26:10,927+0200 FATAL xelatex - Line: 339
```

So where did -8bit go and is there an alternative?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `-8bit` option is valid for the TeX Live implementation of XeTeX; why this isn't accepted by MiKTeX is beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 5):

XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (MiKTeX 2.9) uses option `--enable-8bit-chars` instead of `-8bit`.

Comment: I use version Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit), which is slightly newer, and --enable-8bit-chars still don't work with xelatex, but does work with pdflatex