# tcolorbox listing in XeLaTex compiler

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, minted, polyglossia, arabic

I want to write a document whose main language is Arabic with listings by using the package `\usepackage{polyglossia}`

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[listings,minted,breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1,Path=fonts/]{flat.ttf} %my 
favortie main font
\newfontfamily\timesnewroman[Script=Arabic,Scale=1,Path = fonts/]{times.ttf}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic} %My main & native language
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
هذا كود برمجي بسيط
\begin{english}
\begin{tcblisting}{enhanced,listing only,minted language=latex}
my name is \textcolor{red}{Muhammad}
hi
\end{tcblisting}
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

However, I encountered two problems:

1. Although the output itself is not problematic as shown below,
   [image]
   I get the following message after compiling:

   ```
   Package polyglossia Error: the current roman font does not contain the  Arabic script
   ```

   As an attempt to solve this error, I changed the monofont into an existing custom font and it quite works`\setmonofont[Scale=1,Path = fonts/]{times.ttf}`, 
   but the output looks ugly and there is a problem with the curly brackets as shown below. Is there a way to avoid this error without changing the default mono font or the traditional one?
   [image]
2. Nevertheless the polyglossia problem, when I indent the codes by pressing **Tab**,

   ```
   \documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
   \usepackage[listings,minted,breakable,skins]{tcolorbox} %very essential package to produce chat boxes
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tcblisting}{enhanced,listing only,minted language=latex}
       my name is \textcolor{red}{Muhammad}
       hi
   \end{tcblisting}
   \end{document}
   ```

   The indented spaced are replaced with `^^I`
   [image]
   However, if I switch the compiler to pdflatex, no indented spaces are produced
   [image]

Comment: For the second see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264463/2388

Comment: You do not need `Script=Arabic` option for `times.ttf` because it does not contain arabic script, another thing you have defined `\timesnewroman` font but you did not use it in the first example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In fact, I am newbie in LaTeX using TeXnic center, however I guessed I should put `-8bit` in command line arguments according to the link you commented and the listing works in xelatex as fine as in pdflatex. One another question:  I cannot indent the first line of the code listing, is it normal or there is something wrong?

Comment: @SalimBou If you mean setting the mono font, I haven't set the option `Script=Arabic`.